# String having maximum number of given substrings made after swapping some characters?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

So, this is an interview question that I was going through.

I have strings `a, b, and c`. I want to obtain string `k` by swapping some letters in `a`, so that `k` should contain as many non-overlapping substrings equal either to `b` or `c` as possible. Substring of string `x` is a string formed by consecutive segment of characters from `x`. Two substrings of string `x` overlap if there is position `i` in string `x` occupied by both of them.

Input: The first line contains string a, the second line contains string b, and the third line contains string c (1 ≤ |a|, |b|, |c| ≤ 10^5, where |s| denotes the length of string s).

All three strings consist only of lowercase English letters.

It is possible that b and c coincide.

Output: Find one of possible strings k.

```
Example: 
I/P 
abbbaaccca
ab
aca

O/P
ababacabcc
this optimal solutions has three non-overlaping substrings equal to either b or c on positions 1 – 2 (ab), 3 – 4 (ab), 5 – 7 (aca).
```

Now, the approach that I could think of was to make a character count array for each of the strings, and then proceed ahead. Basically, iterate over the original string (a), check for occurences of b and c. If not there, swap as many characters as possible to make either b or c (whichever is shorter). But, clearly this is not the optimal approach. 
Can anyone suggest something better? (Only pseudocode will be enough)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you'll need to do is count the number of occurrences of each character of each string. The occurrences count of `a` will be your knapsack, whom you'll need to fill with as many `b`'s or `c`'s.

Note that when I say knapsack I mean the character count vector of a, and inserting `b` to `a` will mean reducing the character count vector of `a` by the character count vector of `b`.
I'm a little bit short with my mathematical prove, but you'll need to

1. insert as many `b` as possible to the knapsack
2. Insert as many `c` as possible to the knapsack (in the space that left after 1).
3. If a removal of a `b` from the knapsack will enable an insertion of more `c`, remove `b` from the knapsack. Otherwise, finish.
4. Fill as many `c` that you can to the knapsack
5. Repeat 3-4.

Throughout the program count the number of b and c in the knapsack and the output should be:

```
[b_count times b][c_count times c][char_occurrence_left_in_knapsack_for_char_x times char_x for each char_x in lower_case_english]
```

This should solve your problem at O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that allowed characters have ASCII code 0-127, I would write a function to count the occurence of each character in a string:

```
int[] count(String s) {
    int[] res = new int[128];
    for(int i=0; i<res.length(); i++)
        res[i] = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++)
        res[i]++;
    return res;
}
```

We can now count occurrences in each string:

```
int aCount = count(a);
int bCount = count(b);
int cCount = count(c);
```

We can then write a function to count how many times a string can be carved out of characters of another string:

```
int carveCount(int[] strCount, int[] subStrCount) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<subStrCount.length(); i++) {
        if (subStrCount[i] == 0)
            continue;
        if (strCount[i] >= subStrCount[i])
            min = Math.min(min, strCount[i]-subStrCount[i]);
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<subStrCount.length(); i++) {
        if (subStrCount[i] != 0)
            strStrCount[i] -= min;
    }
    return min;
}
```

and call the function:

```
int bFitCount = carve(aCount, bCount);
int cFitCount = carve(aCount, cCount);
```

EDIT: I didn't realize you wanted all characters originally in a, fixing here.

Finally, to produce the output:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<bFitCount; i++) {
    sb.append(b);
for(int i=0; i<cFitCount; i++) {
    sb.append(c);
for(int i=0; i<aCount.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<aCount[i]; j++) 
        sb.append((char)i);
}
return sb.toString();
```

One more comment: if the goal is to maximize the number of repetitions(b)+repetitions(c), then you may want to first swab b and c if c is shorter. This way if they share some characters you have better chance of increasing the result.

The algorithm could be optimized further, but as it is it should have complexity O(n), where n is the sum of the length of the three strings.

Comment: The code that you have supplied has a lot of errors. The third statement, what is `y`? Also, in the function `carveCount`, what is `Subcount`. Those these are some errors that can be overlooked, but then, the logic according to you is, first check for maximum occurence of shorter string (b or c) and see how many times it can be carved out and then check for longer string. And add the two, right?

Comment: Sorry,  I wrote this on my phone, no way to test. Re the second question, yes if the intent is to maximize the sum (appearances of b + appearance of c), then I believe you need to carve the shortest first

Answer (score 0):

A related problem is called [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).
This is basically the solution described by @Tal Shalti.
I tried to keep everything readable.

My program return `abbcabacac` as one of the string with the most occurences (3).

To get all permutations without repeating a permutation I use `std::next_permutation` from `algorithm`. There not much happening in the main function. I only store the number of occurrences and the permutation, if a higher number of occurrences was achieved.

```
int main()
{
    std::string word = "abbbaaccca";
    std::string patternSmall = "ab";
    std::string patternLarge = "aca";


    unsigned int bestOccurrence = 0;
    std::string bestPermutation = "";


    do {
        // count and remove occurrence
        unsigned int occurrences = FindOccurences(word, patternLarge, patternSmall);

        if (occurrences > bestOccurrence) {
            bestOccurrence = occurrences;
            bestPermutation = word;

            std::cout << word << " .. " << occurences << std::endl;
        }


    } while (std::next_permutation(word.begin(), word.end()));


    std::cout << "Best Permutation " << bestPermutation << "  with " << bestOccurrence << " occurrences." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This function handles the basic algorithm. `pattern1` is the longer pattern, so it will be searched for last. If a pattern is found, it will be replaced with the string "@@", since this should be very rare in the English language.
The variable `occurrenceCounter` keeps track of the number of found occurences.

```
unsigned int FindOccurrences(const std::string& word, const std::string& pattern1, const std::string& pattern2)
{
    unsigned int occurrenceCounter = 0;

    std::string tmpWord(word);

    // '-1' makes implementation of while() easier
    std::string::size_type i = -1;

    i = -1;
    while (FindPattern(tmpWord, pattern2, ++i)) {
        occurrenceCounter++;
        tmpWord.replace(tmpWord.begin() + i, tmpWord.begin() + i + pattern2.size(), "@@");
    }

    i = -1;
    while (FindPattern(tmpWord, pattern1, ++i)) {
        occurrenceCounter++;
        tmpWord.replace(tmpWord.begin() + i, tmpWord.begin() + i + pattern1.size(), "@@");
    }

    return occurrenceCounter;
}
```

This function returns the first position of the found pattern. If the pattern is not found, `std::string::npos` is returned by `string.find(...)`. Also `string.find(...)` starts to search for the pattern starting by index `i`.

```
bool FindPattern(const std::string& word, const std::string& pattern, std::string::size_type& i)
{
      std::string::size_type foundPosition = word.find(pattern, i);

      if (foundPosition == std::string::npos) {
         return false;
      }

      i = foundPosition;

     return true;
}
```

Comment: In the `Findoccurences` function, I didn't really get the part when you get the relevant substring using `unsigned int finish = pattern1.size() + pattern2.size() - 1;
        std::string strSub = tmpWord.substr(i, finish);`. I mean, what does finish represent here? Can you be a little more elaborative?

Comment: This is an error in my code. I try to get the area around pattern1 that can overlap with pattern2. So I start at the beginning of pattern1 `i`, go the distance of pattern1 `pattern1.size()`, go back one character `-1`, and go the distance of pattern2 `pattern2.size()`. But forget that, I change(d) that part of the code.